# Android accessibility viewPager read two views

Tags: android, android-viewpager, talkback

I'm using Talkback to read the content of the views on my ViewPager, and it's reading the content of the current view and the content of the next view (not visible).

For example

View 1

TextView -> hi1
TextView -> bye1

View2

TextView -> hi2
TextView -> bye2

Talkback read hi1, hi2, bye1, bye2

I've tried to change the value of pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(), but it doesn't do anything, Talkback always read the current view and the next one, even if the value of OffScreenPageLimit is 4 (it should read the next 2 views).

The only info I've found is that: https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/issues/detail?id=139

Any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I did a workaround for the special case I needed, sorry

Comment: @jegumi : can you share your workaround solution for this problem? I also have the same problem

Comment: @ManishAgrawat I'm afraid I don't have access to that old code anymore. I think what I did was to play with the accesibilityManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager.html) and accesibilityEvents (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html) to disable/enable the talkback in certain cases

Comment: This appears to have finally been fixed in TalkBack 4.5.0 (released on 4/27/2016.)

Answer (score 3):

You can create `event` custom Accessibility event inside the OnChangePageView and save the string you want to read in a list and get position from interface between Activity/fragment and adapter.

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(isTalkbackActive(getApplicationContext())) {
                AccessibilityEvent event = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
                if (onPageChangeInterface != null) {
                    String text = onPageChangeInterface.getTextToRead(position);
                    event.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT);
                    event.getText().add(text);
                    viewPagerWallets.requestFocus();
                    viewPagerWallets.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
                    accessibilityManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event);

                }
            }
        }

    };
```

Then the same string that you saved you add it in ContentDescription of the relative that you have all the view only in the first position.

```
ArrayList readAccessibilityValues = new ArrayList<>();
 String valor = valor + txtView1.getText()+",";
    valor = valor + txtView2.getText()+",";
    if(position == 0) {
        relativeGeneral.setContentDescription(valor);
    }
 readAccessibilityValues.add(valor);
```

I think it's not the best solution but I have not found another

Comment: what is 'onPageChangeInterface' over here. Also give me explanation on viewPagerWallets

Comment: This is cut-paste answer, if not complete then its useless.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you to get into the right direction:

```
pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        super.onPageSelected(position)

        val event = AccessibilityEvent.obtain()

        event.eventType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT
        event.text.add("Hello TalkBack!")

        val accessibilityManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) as AccessibilityManager
        accessibilityManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event)
    }
})
```

Simply replace "Hello Talkback!" by any string you would like to be read when changing a page in ViewPager.